# Bluebird Promise Scope

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have just started using promises in attempt to cleanup some 'callback hell'.

I've decided on trying bluebird and I am running it in the browser but immediately ran into scoping problems.

Is there a way of setting the thisArg in a new Promise? The below example shows that the 'this' value inside the promise resolver is set to the browser window, but I'd like it set to the surrounding scope so I can easily access member variables.

I noticed there is a .bind() method but it only scopes the 'then()' method, not the promise. I also realize I can have 'var me = this' just before the promise and use closure, but I wanted to avoid it if possible.

```
function MyObject() {
    this.value = 7;
}

MyObject.prototype.getValue = function () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        // some request/processing that takes a long time
        var result = Ajax.request(...);

        resolve({
            value: this.value,
            result: result
        });
        // 'this' is set to window instead of the instance,
        // resulting in this.value as undefined
    });
}

var obj = new MyObject();
obj.getValue().then(function (value) {
    console.log(value); // preferably outputs 7
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. You can of course [use the default approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback), but you shouldn't need to.

When doing heavy processing and getting back the value asynchronously, you want to get a promise *for the value*. You don't need to set the result value as a property of the original instance.

```
MyObject.prototype.getValue = function () {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        // lots of processing to make a `value`
        resolve(value); // no `this` at all!
    });
};
```

In case you want to synchronously get the `.value` that you had set on the instance, you don't need the `Promise` constructor. Just use [`Promise.resolve`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promiseresolvedynamic-value---promise) to make a promise for an existing value:

```
MyObject.prototype.getValue = function () {
    // TODO: lots of processing
    return Promise.resolve(this.value);
};
```

Or, in your case, even [`Promise.method`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisemethodfunction-fn---function):

```
// TODO: lots of processing
MyObject.prototype.getValue = Promise.method(function () {
    return this.value;
});
```

Comment: So I'm trying see the general rule, the promise should return *nothing* but what is generated/fetched inside of itself?

What if I wish to augment my returned result with values that I already have on my instance?

I'm just trying to avoid anti-patterns. I realize my example can use Promise.resolve, but say it wanted to include this.value along with the results of maybe an Ajax call.

Comment: I think you should emphasize what `Promise.method` does here, it solves this problem exactly. Also, that there is no point in returning a promise `this.value` if there are no async calculations involved.

Comment: @BrendanAnnable you should _only_ use the promise constructor for writing logic converting callback code to promisified code - for chains you have `.bind`.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum: I think the reason to return a promise here was `TODO: lots of processing` that should be fixed without changing the return type (API).

Comment: @BrendanAnnable: Yes, what is returned from a `Promise` constructor promise should only be what is generated/fetched inside it - often you don't even need to use the `Promise` constructor but can do it with [promisification](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification). Augmenting the instance with the result is an antipattern, augmenting the result with instance values can be done in `.then()` callbacks (which might be bound) - for examples see t.niese's comment-answer.

Comment: In the second code block (which only creates the resolved promise at the end) there is the risk of throwing a synchronous exception which would be very bad if the function is "documented" to return a Promise.  A promise-returning function should never throw a synchronous exception.

Comment: @dmansfield: Of course, there's always the risk of developer mistakes. But exceptions stemming from those cannot be handled programmatically, so it's not that bad. But you're right, one should not deliberately `throw` from a promise-returning function, it would have to be `return Promise.reject(…)` in the second snippet.

Answer (score 2):

This is more a comment then an answer, as it is primary opinion based.

In the rar situations where I need this it would look like this in my code:

`Ajax.requestAsync` in this case would be a promisifyed version of `Ajax.request`.

I know this might just move your problem to another place.

```
MyObject.prototype.getValue = function () {
    return Ajax.requestAsync(...)
    .bind(this)
    .then(function(result) {
        return {
              value: this.value,
              result: result
            }
    });
}
```

Or something like this:

```
 MyObject.prototype.getValue = function () {
    var returnValue = {
        value: this.value
    };

    return Ajax.requestAsync(...)
    .then(function(result) {
        returnValue.result = result;
        return returnValue;
    });
}
```

A rarely use such constructs:

```
MyObject.prototype.getValue = function () {
  return Promise.all([this, Ajax.requestAsync(...)])
  .spread(function(object, result) {
      return {
        value: object.value,
        result: result
      };
  });
}
```